# Flowtype: Refining arrays

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

So I'm using React and I have the following code:

```
type Props = {
  children: SuperOption | HTMLHrElement | Array<SuperOption | HtmlHrElement>,
 }
```

And then further down in my code, I have:

```
let arr: Array<SuperOption | HtmlHrElement>;
if (this.props.children.length) {
  arr = this.props.children;
} else {
  arr = [this.props.children];
}
```

This gives me a flow errors:

```
HTMLHRElement This type is incompatible with array type
SuperOption This type is incompatible with array type
```

I think it's because flow doesn't know that I'm trying to refine it to the array by doing `this.props.children.length`, what's the proper way to refine it to an array type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to refine the array is using `Array.isArray` function:

```
if (Array.isArray(this.props.children)) {
  arr = this.props.children;
} else {
  arr = [this.props.children];
}
```

Comment: The even better answer to this question is to use `React.Children.toArray` etc, since it covers all the other cases that my primitive method didn't. :) https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren I'm a noob.